# Are anime OP/ED theme songs original?

Tags: anime-history

Are anime OP/ED theme songs original? Is it like after creating an anime, the producer hires a singer to sing a song for the OP/ED theme for that anime, or do they just use songs that the singer already sang for his album or something like that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The vast majority of the time (easily upwards of 95% of the time, by my estimate), OPs/EDs are produced specifically for the anime they're used in. Reuse of existing songs is rare.

There are counterexamples, though, which by their very rarity prove the rule. A few select examples:

- *Erased* reused Asian Kung Fu Generation's 2004 song "Re:Re".
- *JoJo's Bizarre Adventure* (2012 version) reused [Yes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yes_(band))'s 1968 song "Roundabout".
- *Speed Grapher* reused Duran Duran's 1981 song "Girls on Film". ([Thanks, @ConMan.](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/31790/are-anime-op-ed-theme-songs-original/31792#comment44253_31792))
- *One Week Friends* reused Sukima Switch's 2004 song "Kanade", though in this case, it was re-recorded with Amamiya Sora (voice actor of the character Fujimiya Kaori) as the vocalist.
- And, of course, *Neon Genesis Evangelion* uses [a great many different recordings and mixes](http://vgmdb.net/album/19791) of the classic "Fly Me to the Moon" as its ending theme.

Comment: A few other notable ones include *Speed Grapher*, which in Japan used Duran Duran's "Girls on Film" as its opening, and if you include cover songs then there are also ones like *One Week Friends* whose ED was Sukima Switch's Kanade reworked as a character song for Kaori, or the thousand-and-one covers of the jazz standard "Fly Me To The Moon" on *Neon Genesis Evangelion*, although in all of those cases they were definitely recorded for the show, just not written for it.